# Should default case always be the last in switch statement?

Tags: php, switch-statement

So, for example, if i have code that looks like this

```
$a=5;
switch($a){
     case 1: echo "one"; break;
     default: echo "two"; break;
     case 10: echo "ten"; break;
}
```

Is that a bad idea? What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Why don't you try and see whether anything goes wrong? It's rather simple and easy to test.

Comment: Short answer: You can do it, but you won't see it very often! I would put it always at the bottom so that you always know where it is if there is one

Comment: Simply for the sake of readability, it's best to put a default as the last entry in a switch statement

Comment: @Epodax Already did. Worked out just as expected. But a little search gave no results of anybody using such structure. Maybe that's a reason of programming practices or there could be some pitfalls with this. Just asking for clarification.